# How to emphasize that function may throw?

Tags: c++, exception, throw

Consider the following function:

```
void checkPlayerCounter() {
    if (playerCounter != consts::numberOfPlayers) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Detected " + std::to_string(playerCounter)
          + " player instead of " + std::to_string(consts::numberOfPlayers));
    }
}
```

The function may throw, and for readibility I want to emphasize that in the function's declaration inside header file. How can I do that?

I am looking for something like:

```
void checkPlayerCounter() may throw;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `noexcept(false)` explicitly. Right where you suggested:

```
void checkPlayerCounter() noexcept(false);
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid the double negative with `noexcept`. Another option is a comment:

```
void checkPlayerCounter(); // may throw
```

That said, whoever reads the declaration should always assume that the function may throw, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: You can use a macro: `#define MAY_THROW noexcept(false)`

Comment: @Brian With that approach though, there is no way to avoid using a macro :)

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
/**
 * @throws std::runtime_error
 */
void checkPlayerCounter();
```